# Geometric intuition for why an element of an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1 is equal to its cofactor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I recently learnt that each element of an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1 is equal to its cofactor. I have been trying to understand what this means geometrically given that the absolute value of the determinant of a matrix is the volume of the n-dimensional parallelotope whose sides are given by the column vectors of the matrix. But I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Can someone please give the geometric intuition behind why this fact about orthogonal matrices is true and how it might be proven geometrically? Thanks!

Comment: So you *do* understand why it's true based on the cofactor formula for $A^{-1}$, which equals $A^\top$ for an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I do.

Comment: So the issue is why the signed $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped obtained by projecting the columns except the $j$th on the hyperplane $x_i=0$ is equal to $a_{ij}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, that's correct. I'm unable to see why that is true.

Comment: The only way I can see it geometrically is through exterior algebra and the Hodge star operator. If you're familiar with these, I’ll post an answer.

Comment: P.S. For the case $n=3$, you can see the crux of the argument in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2731376).

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not familiar with those.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. Later, I will post an answer anyway for others who may happen upon this question.

Comment: If you're just looking for informal geometric intuition as opposed to a formal geometric proof like Ted provided, one way of thinking about it is that an orthogonal matrix of determinant 1 acts on hyperplanes "in the same way" it acts on their normal vectors. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4835337/129912) for a description using the cross product, although it's just Hodge star in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know a geometric argument other than to use the geometry of $k$-vectors $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k\in\Lambda^k\Bbb R^n$. The oriented $k$-dimensional parallelepiped spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_k\in\Bbb R^n$ corresponds to the $k$-vector $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k$. Moreover, the Hodge star operator $\star\colon\Lambda^k\Bbb R^n\to\Lambda^{n-k}\Bbb R^n$ is defined for every $k=0,1,\dots,n$, with the property that it is linear and satisfies $\star e_I = \pm e_{I'}$ for the standard orthonormal basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$, with $I$ a multi-index and $I'$ the complementary multi-index, the sign being chosen so that $e_I\wedge\star e_I = e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n$. Given the inner product on $\Bbb R^n$, we induce an inner product on $\Lambda^k\Bbb R^n$ by declaring $\{e_I: I \text{ an increasing multi-index}\}$ to be an orthonormal basis. The key geometric fact, then, is that $\star$ is an isometry: For any $\omega,\tau\in\Lambda^k\Bbb R^n$,
$$\langle\omega,\tau\rangle = \langle\star\omega,\star\tau\rangle.$$
In general, $\omega\wedge\star\omega = \langle\omega,\omega\rangle e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n$. Letting $\omega=v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k$, the ($k$-dimensional) volume of the $k$-dimensional parallelepiped spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is $\sqrt{\langle\omega,\omega\rangle}$. You can visualize the Hodge star operator as mapping an oriented $k$-dimensional parallelepiped to an oriented $(n-k)$-dimensional parallelepiped orthogonal to it and having the same volume (different-dimensional volumes, of course).

**REMARK**: You can deduce various generalizations of the Pythagorean theorem from this. For example, if $v_1,v_2\in\Bbb R^3$, you see that the area $\mathcal A$ of the parallelogram they span satisfies
$$\mathcal A^2 = \langle v_1\wedge v_2,v_1\wedge v_2\rangle = \mathcal A_1^2+ \mathcal A_2^2+ \mathcal A_3^2,$$
where $\mathcal A_i$ is the area of the projection of the parallelogram on the plane $x_i=0$.

Now we can deduce your result. Let $A$ be your $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$; $a_{ij}$ denotes the $ij$-entry and $A_{ij}$ the $ij$-cofactor.  Indeed, let $v_j=Ae_j$ be the $j$th column of $A$, $j=1,\dots,n$. The fact that $\det A = 1$ translates to $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_n = e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n$. Just as $a_{ij} = \langle v_j, e_i\rangle$, you can check that $A_{ij}=\langle \star v_j,\star e_i\rangle$.
For example with $i=j=1$, $\star v_1 = v_2\wedge\dots\wedge v_n$ since $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_n = e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n$. If you expand this wedge product in terms of the matrix entries, you'll see that
\begin{align*}
v_2\wedge\dots\wedge v_n &= \left(\sum a_{i_12}e_{i_1}\right)\wedge\left(\sum a_{i_23}e_{i_2}\right)\wedge\dots\wedge\left(\sum a_{i_{n-1}n}e_{i_{n-1}}\right) \\ &= \sum a_{i_12}a_{i_23}\dots a_{i_{n-1}n} e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_{n-1}}.
\end{align*}
Using the definition of determinant and the alternating property of $\wedge$, we conclude that, summing over all permutations $\sigma$ of $\{2,\dots,n\}$,
$$\langle v_2\wedge\dots\wedge v_n,e_2\wedge\dots\wedge e_n\rangle = \sum_\sigma (-1)^{\text{sgn}\,\sigma}a_{\sigma(2)2}a_{\sigma(3)3}\dots a_{\sigma(n)n} = A_{11}.$$
Finally,
$$a_{11}=\langle v_1,e_1 \rangle = \langle \star v_1,\star e_1\rangle = \langle v_2\wedge\dots\wedge v_n,e_2\wedge\dots\wedge e_n\rangle = A_{11}.$$
The statement that $a_{ij} = A_{ij}$ follows in the identical manner; it is notationally messier, and we'll skip it here.